# Indicator is not running as hitting "Internal Server Study Error"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When adding the indicator, I am seeing the error - Internal Server Study error

Summary - I am trying to build a screener where I am calling a user defined function for my watchlist scrips. it will add the scrip name, entry level into an array of object. Finally I am printing the array as a table on the chart. The user defined function adds the scrips into the array if it finds rsi divergence.

Can anyone please help me in guiding where the below code is going wrong -

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = 'ps_screener', shorttitle = 'PS',overlay = true)

var resultNo = 0     // initializes consistent variable contains total no of results
var prevResultNo = 0 // initializes consistent variable contains total no of results from previous execution

// define a new object type
type resultItem
    int s
    string sym
    float ent
    string rsn
    string dt
// define array of user defined object to hold the result of screener
var array<resultItem> results = na
results := array.new<resultItem>()

screeningStrategy = '=====Screener Strategy ==============='
screenerStrategy1 = input.bool(title = 'RSI Divergence', defval = true, tooltip = 'Choose this option if want to screen based on RSI divergence', group = screeningStrategy)
//screenerStrategy2 = input.bool(title = 'Pivot-PDH breakout', defval = true, tooltip = 'Choose this option if want to screen based on Pivot breakout', group = screeningStrategy)
//screenerStrategy3 = input.bool(title = 'Candle Pattern', defval = true, tooltip = 'Choose this option if want to screen based on Candle Pattern', group = screeningStrategy)


timeframeHeader = '=======Time Frame ====================='
timeframe = input.timeframe(defval = '15', title = 'TimeFrame', options = ['5','15','30','60','D','W','M'], group = timeframeHeader)

tableLocationHeader = '========= Table Location ================'
location = input.string(defval = 'Top', title = 'Table Location', options = ['Top', 'Middle','Bottom'], group = tableLocationHeader)
tableLocation = location == 'Top' ? position.top_right : location == 'Middle' ? position.middle_right : position.bottom_right


// user defined function to print 2D array
//print_table(sno, symbol, entry, reason, dtime) =>
print_table() =>
    //printInd = resultInd.new(sno, symbol, entry, reason, dtime)
    //array.push(results, printInd)
    t = table.new(position = tableLocation, columns = 5, rows = array.size(results), border_width = 1, border_color = color.black)
    i = 0
    for eachResult in results
        if i < array.size(results) - 1
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = i, text = str.tostring(eachResult.s), bgcolor = color.new(color.yellow,80))
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 1, row = i, text = eachResult.sym, bgcolor =color.new(color.yellow,80))
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 2, row = i, text = str.tostring(eachResult.ent), bgcolor = color.new(color.yellow,80))
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 3, row = i, text = eachResult.rsn, bgcolor = color.new(color.yellow,80))
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 4, row = i, text = eachResult.dt, bgcolor = color.new(color.yellow,80))         
        else
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 0, row = i, text = str.tostring(eachResult.s), bgcolor = color.yellow)
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 1, row = i, text = eachResult.sym, bgcolor = color.yellow)
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 2, row = i, text = str.tostring(eachResult.ent), bgcolor = color.yellow)
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 3, row = i, text = eachResult.rsn, bgcolor = color.yellow)
            table.cell(table_id = t, column = 4, row = i, text = eachResult.dt, bgcolor = color.yellow)        
        i := i + 1

inRange(cond) =>
    rangeUpper = 60
    rangeLower = 5
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper


// define function to identify rsi divergence
calculate_rsi_div(symbol, timeperiod) =>
    len = 14 
    src = request.security(symbol, timeperiod, close)
    lbR = 5
    lbL = 5
    rangeUpper = 60
    rangeLower = 5
    osc = ta.rsi(src, len)
    plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
    phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

    entry_reason = ""
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Regular Bullish
    // Osc: Higher Low
    oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and inRange(plFound[1]) // current RSI more than prev pivot low RSI and in range of 60 and 5
    // Price: Lower Low
    priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1) // current low price less than prev pivot low price
    bullCond = priceLL and oscHL and plFound
    
    // Hidden Bullish
    // Osc: Lower Low
    oscLL = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and inRange(plFound[1])
    // Price: Higher Low
    priceHL = low[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
    hiddenBullCond = priceHL and oscLL and plFound

    // Regular Bearish
    // Osc: Lower High
    oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and inRange(phFound[1])
    // Price: Higher High
    priceHH = high[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)
    bearCond = priceHH and oscLH and phFound

    // Hidden Bearish
    // Osc: Higher High
    oscHH = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and inRange(phFound[1])
    // Price: Lower High
    priceLH = high[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)
    hiddenBearCond = priceLH and oscHH and phFound


    if bullCond
        entry_reason := 'Bull'
    else if hiddenBullCond
        entry_reason := 'Up'
    else if bearCond
        entry_reason := 'Bear'
    else if hiddenBearCond
        entry_reason := 'Down'

    entryPrice = request.security(symbol, timeperiod, open, ignore_invalid_symbol = true)

    if (bullCond or hiddenBullCond or bearCond or hiddenBearCond)
        entry_time = str.format('{0,date,yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss}',time_close(timeperiod, syminfo.session, syminfo.timezone))
        ri = resultItem.new(resultNo, symbol, entryPrice, entry_reason, entry_time)
        array.push(results, ri)
        


// Watchlist
symbol1 = 'BINANCE:ADAUSDT'
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:ATOMUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:BNBUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:BTCUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:CHRUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:COCOSUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:COTIUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:DGBUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:DOGEUSDT')
array.push(symbolList,'BINANCE:EOSUSDT')



if screenerStrategy1
    calculate_rsi_div(symbol1,timeframe)

//print indications only on last bar
if barstate.islast
    resultNo := array.size(results)
    if prevResultNo == 0  // this is first execution of the session
        prevResultNo := resultNo
    else if resultNo - prevResultNo > 1 // this is subsequent execution where more new results came, so we need to remove first element from array
        array.shift(results)
    print_table() // finally printing array elements
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, 'symbolList' is not declared before you use it.